# cakephp reading a session variable

Tags: session, cakephp

I've created a page that requires a session variable which will be inserted into a form. The problem I'm having is my `Session->read();` is putting the variable into the right field in my form.

here is the controller where the session variable(last) is created

```
function add($last=null){

    $accounttemplates=$this->Template->find('list', array(
    'fields'=>array('name'),
    'conditions' => array(
    'account_id' => $this->Auth->user('account_id'))));


        //retrieve Account Id of current User       
        $accountid=$this->Auth->user('account_id');

        $templatefields=$this->Field->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array(
        'Field.template_id' => "10002")));

        $this->set('accountid', $accountid); 
        $this->set('templatefields', $templatefields); 

        $this->set('accounttemplates', $accounttemplates);

    if($this->request->is('post'))
    {

    $this->Field->create(); 

    if ($this->Field->save($this->request->data))
    {   
        if($this->request->data['submit'] == "type_1") 
            {

                $last=$this->Session->write('last', $this->data['Field']['template_id']);
                $this->Session->setFlash('The field has been saved');  
                $this->redirect( array('controller' => 'fields','action' => 'add_again',$last));
            } 
            if($this->request->data['submit'] == "type_2") 
            { 
                $this->Session->setFlash('The template has been saved'); 
                $this->redirect( array('controller' => 'templates','action' => 'index'));
            } 


    }
    else
    {
        $this->Session->setFlash('The field could not be saved. Please, try again.'); 
    } 
 }

     $this->set('last', $last); 


  }
```

in this function is where the session variable is read.

```
function add_again($last=null){

    $accounttemplates=$this->Template->find('list', array(
    'fields'=>array('name'),
    'conditions' => array(
    'account_id' => $this->Auth->user('account_id'))));


        //retrieve Account Id of current User       
        //$accountid=$this->Auth->user('account_id');

        $templatefields=$this->Field->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array(
        'Field.template_id' => "10002")));

        //$this->set('accountid', $accountid); 
        $this->set('templatefields', $templatefields); 
        $last=$this->Session->read('last');
        $this->set('accounttemplates', $accounttemplates);

    if($this->request->is('post'))
    {

    $this->Field->create(); 

    if ($this->Field->save($this->request->data))
    {   
        if($this->request->data['submit'] == "type_1") 
            {
                $this->Session->setFlash('The field has been saved');  
                $this->redirect( array('controller' => 'fields','action' => 'add_again'));
            } 
            if($this->request->data['submit'] == "type_2") 
            { 
                $this->Session->setFlash('The template has been saved'); 
                $this->redirect( array('controller' => 'templates','action' => 'index'));
            } 


    }
    else
    {
        $this->Session->setFlash('The field could not be saved. Please, try again.'); 
    } 




  }
}
```

here is the form im trying to input the variable $last into

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Field', array('action'=>'add'));?>
                        <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('name', array('label'=>false)); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('description', array('label'=>false)); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('default_value', array('label'=>false)); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('template_id', array('value' => $last, 'type'=>'text'));?></td>
                    <?php   echo $this->Form->hidden('active',array('default'=>'1')); ?>
```

in the first function is where the session variable last is created, im trying to put that variable in the view into the template_id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't set the variable `$last` into your `add_again()` method. Just write the following line below where you are reading the value from session.

```
 $last = $this->Session->read('last');
 $this->set('last', $last); // write this line just below the above line.
```